# Отправка textarea.value на сервер через AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, клиент-сервер

Есть поле <input>, есть ajax, через который передаю значение этого поля. Если пользователь захочет написать в поле:

'blablabla&par=value'

В этом случае отошлется только левая часть (до первого &), как можно сделать так, чтобы отослался весь текст?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите сделать GET запрос попробуйте отправить его так. http://localhost.loc&input=blablabla?par=value. На сервер можно будет получить значение этих полей input и par которые будут содержать (blablabla и value)

Comment: Нет, я хочу сделать POST запрос, передавая значения как в этом комментарии или посте, при этом чтобы эти знаки не учитывались, возможно уже нашел ответ (использовать escape() или encodeURIComponent() в JS. Если сработает то оставлю здесь ответ